# How to get tab and set it as default in angular with angular material Tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, tabs

I have a component inside another big component (parent). The big component has the tabs feature and to access those tabs inside the inner component im doing the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tab-group');
```

That above code outputs me an array of length 2 because there is another tab. So to access the last one and set the default tab im doing the following:

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tab-group');
if (tabs.length > 0) {
    tabs[tabs.length - 1]['selectedIndex'] = 3;
}
```

But that does nothing. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Note**: I cant touch parent component. Only the inner one.

Comment: Nope. This is not how Angular works. `querySelectorAll`, `getElementById` etc. These things have nothing to do in an Angular app. This is not how you set a class or an attribute. Angular manipulates the _data_ and then this data gets reflected in the view, not the opposite. You don't _select_ DOM elements in Angular, you manipulate the _data_ that generates your DOM elements.

Comment: This is for testing purposes, not real app. Thnk you.

Comment: Testing purposes, real app, what's the difference? That's not the way Angular works in either case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the official documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

 Here it says there is an attribute called **"selectedIndex"** which determines which tab should be chosen. You dont need no querySelector or any javascript related stuff.
Here is an example on how to dynmically change the tab just by the selectedIndex value:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/xamqklmnbkkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts

 Hope it helps!